# New row in spreadsheet to add column using row ID number in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

For every row thats added, I want to automatically add an ID column using the row number, ideally in another sheet as a new row.

I started using this `TEXT(ROW()-1,"000")`. This would output 001 for row 2 etc. **Perfect**.

You can edit this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oAtDLo2Bk-3SaUAYX9GrscC6DN_h8lO8pqLUWPTAoJw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B8:B="",,TEXT(ROW(A1:A), "000")))
```

[image: 0]